# TypeORM, How to create PrimaryGeneratedColumn with a prefix

Tags: sql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I'm using TypeORM and want to create PrimaryGeneratedColumn as zerofill value with a prefix, like PR000001, PR000002 and so on. How can I get that?
Now I found [EntityListeners](http://typeorm.io/#/listeners-and-subscribers), so I can create a regular PrimaryGeneratedColumn and just add zerofill value with a prefix onInstert, onUpdate and so on, but it doesn't look like a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anybody curious about, I found a hacky-solution

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class MyEntitySubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface {

    public afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<any>) {
        const repo = event.manager.connection.getRepository(MyEntity);
        event.entity.prefixedId = `PR${zerofill(6, event.entity.id)}`;
        repo.save(event.entity);
    }

}
```

also, related ticket https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1571